# Gmail app: How can I view the email addresses?

Tags: email, gmail, 1.5-cupcake

In the gmail app, how can I view the actual email addresses an email has been sent to, rather than just the name. Sometimes the person in question has more than one email address and it would be useful to see which email address was used.

The only method I've come up with so far is to hit reply all and then scroll around the cc: field, but that is clunky, particularly if there are quite a few recipients. Any better options?

I am using Android 1.5 on a T-Mobile Pulse (aka Huawei U8220).

Comment: I can't find a way -- very annoying!

Comment: I don't see any other way on my Moto Droid/2.2-Froyo, either.

Comment: My Magic 32A with CM6 allows me to view the email address. I think you need the latest GMail app in order to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The latest version of the Gmail app (it has not been released yet, but you can find a copy of a leaked official APK floating around somewhere) has this feature. It adds a "more details" link on every email header so you can see the actual email addresses used.

I'm not sure whether this version will work on 1.5 and up, as Google hasn't said anything yet. I know that part of their work in 2.2 was better separating the Google apps like Gmail from the rest of the platform, so that they could ship updates through the Market. So it's possible that this will only become available for 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

I have Froyo (2.2), and it allows you to double-tap the Sender's line

If the email address is not in the contacts database, it shows you the address and asks you if you want to create an entry

If the address is in the email address, a set of icons appear (mail, text, IM, etc...) The Contacts icon takes you to the user info.

Not sure what happens if Contact has two emails, trying to setup test (will run tomorrow).